# how to come up with an n by 4 matrix in php

Tags: php, matrix

I have an assignment to come up with a matrix in php as shown below

[image]

The matrix is such that when you input a value of say 32, it give you the matrix in the picture above. When you input 31, it gives you the matrix above excluding the last column so it appears as if it accepts numbers divisible by 4. If the modulus of the number is greater than 0 then it prints a matrix of the previous number divisible by 4.

Below is my code which only prints the last row of the matrix. I couldn't get to present the matrix as in the picture above.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // Create an array of n-items on the fly
    /**
    function series($num_elements)
    {
        return array_fill(0, $num_elements, null);
    }
    **/
    //var_dump(series(400));

    // Collect the value entered and process
    $boltnumbers = $_REQUEST['boltnumbers'];
    if (empty($boltnumbers)) {
        // Print out the empty error string
        echo "you must provide a bolting sequence!";
    }
    else
    {
        // Get all the variables to be used for the matrix
        $limit = ($boltnumbers / 4);            
        $count = 1;

        for ($i=4; $i < $limit; $i++) { 

            $series[$count] = 4 * ($i - 3);
            $count++;               

            for ($i=4; $i < $limit; $i++) { 

                $series[$count] = 4 * ($i - 2);
                $count++;

                for ($i=4; $i < $limit; $i++) { 

                    $series[$count] = 4 * ($i - 1);
                    $count++;

                    for ($i=4; $i < $limit; $i++) { 

                        $series[$count] = 4 * $i;
                        $count++;

                        for ($i=4; $i < $limit; $i++) { 

                                $series[$count] = 4 * ($i + 1);                                 
                                $count++;
                        }                           
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        $count = $count - 1;
        $j = 1;

        echo"<table>";
        for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) { 
            echo"<tr>";
                for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++) { 
                    echo"<td>";
                        echo $series[$j];
                    echo "</td>";
                    $j++;
                    if ($j > $count) {
                        echo $j;
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            echo"</tr>";
        }
        echo"</table>";         
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, 5 `for`-s deep..

Comment: @FirstOne: I was actually converting a vb code to php so wanted to see how the thing works in php first hand before code optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can minimize the code to:

```
$boltnumbers = 32;  //Hardcoded for easier reference

$limit = ((int)($boltnumbers / 4)) * 4; //Getting the limit so here, 32/4 = 4 * 4 = 32, 31/4 = 7 * 4 = 28

$nos = range(1, $limit);  //Create array with the range of numbers for demonstration purpose (you can omit this as well, but change "echo $nos[$j];" to "echo ($j+1);" 

echo"<table>";
for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) { 
    echo"<tr>";
    for ($j= $i; $j < $limit; $j+=4) { 
        echo"<td>";
        echo $nos[$j];   // You can also use "echo ($j+1);" without array
        echo"</td>";
    }
    echo"</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
```

**Result** - for 32

```
1   5   9   13  17  21  25  29
2   6   10  14  18  22  26  30
3   7   11  15  19  23  27  31
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32
```

**Result** - for 31

```
1   5   9   13  17  21  25
2   6   10  14  18  22  26
3   7   11  15  19  23  27
4   8   12  16  20  24  28
```

Comment: To prevent misunderstandings, this is happening: `((int)($boltnumbers  / 4)) * 4`.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a code that uses only 1 `for` and fills a 'matrix' with the values. Here it is:

```
$end = 32;
$m = array(); // final matrix

$end = floor($end /4) * 4; // make it count only until it fits the rule in the question

$col = 0;
for($i = 1; $i <= $end; $i++){
    $col = $i % 4 == 0 ? 0 : $col+1;

    if(!isset($m[$col])){
        $m[$col] = array();
    }

    $m[$col][] = $i;
}
```

---

That could provide you some **flexibility** when it comes to displaying the values. If you just want to put them in a table, do it like so:

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($m as $v){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($v as $n){
        echo "<td>$n</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

---

The output for `32`:

```
1   5   9   13  17  21  25  29
2   6   10  14  18  22  26  30
3   7   11  15  19  23  27  31
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32
```

The output for `31`:

```
1   5   9   13  17  21  25
2   6   10  14  18  22  26
3   7   11  15  19  23  27
4   8   12  16  20  24  28
```